# itemize and enumerate with package enumitem

Tags: enumerate, itemize, enumitem

Sorry for having tomatoes on my eyes, but why does my lists myitemize and myenumerate not work properly?

```
\documentclass[pagesize,parskip=half,DIV=11]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize,1]{itemsep=0pt,label=•,leftmargin=*,labelsep=4.5mm,after=\smallskip}
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate]{leftmargin=*,labelsep=3mm,after=\smallskip}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item damit lässt sich im Idealfall zeigen, welche wissenschaftlichen Auswirkungen bestimmte publizierte Ergebnisse, Ansätze oder Theorien hatten, indem diese von anderen aufgeriffen, verwendet und möglicherweise weiter entwickelt wurden
\item welche Ansätze, Hypothesen, Theorien bzw. welche publizierenden Autoren besonders häufig übernommen wurden
\end{itemize}

\begin{myitemize}
\item damit lässt sich im Idealfall zeigen, welche wissenschaftlichen Auswirkungen bestimmte publizierte Ergebnisse, Ansätze oder Theorien hatten, indem diese von anderen aufgeriffen, verwendet und möglicherweise weiter entwickelt wurden
\item welche Ansätze, Hypothesen, Theorien bzw. welche publizierenden Autoren besonders häufig übernommen wurden
\end{myitemize}

%\begin{myenumerate}
%\item damit lässt sich im Idealfall zeigen, welche wissenschaftlichen Auswirkungen bestimmte publizierte Ergebnisse, Ansätze oder Theorien hatten, indem diese von anderen aufgeriffen, verwendet und möglicherweise weiter entwickelt wurden,\footnote{Dieser Umstand ist in jedem Fall besonders von wissenschaftshistorischem Interesse\index{wissenschaftshistorisches Interesse} (vgl. jedoch auch die vorhandene, im Text w.\,u. zitierte Kritik, die an der Auswertung von Zitationsdatenbanken\index{Zitationsdatenbank} besteht).}
%\item welche Ansätze, Hypothesen, Theorien bzw. welche publizierenden Autoren besonders häufig übernommen wurden,\footnote{Auch die rein quantitative Auswertung von Zitationsdatenbanken wird häufig als ein Aspekt der Auswertung in Evaluierungsverfahren\index{Evaluierungsverfahren} gesehen.}
%\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX:SE!

For `myenumerate` you forgot to define labels. This should work:

```
\documentclass[pagesize,parskip=half,DIV=11]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize,1]{itemsep=0pt,label=•,leftmargin=*,labelsep=4.5mm,after=\smallskip}
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate]{label=\arabic*.,  % <----
                     leftmargin=*,labelsep=3mm,after=\smallskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item damit lässt sich im Idealfall zeigen, welche wissenschaftlichen Auswirkungen bestimmte publizierte Ergebnisse, Ansätze oder Theorien hatten, indem diese von anderen aufgeriffen, verwendet und möglicherweise weiter entwickelt wurden
\item welche Ansätze, Hypothesen, Theorien bzw. welche publizierenden Autoren besonders häufig übernommen wurden
\end{itemize}

\begin{myitemize}
\item damit lässt sich im Idealfall zeigen, welche wissenschaftlichen Auswirkungen bestimmte publizierte Ergebnisse, Ansätze oder Theorien hatten, indem diese von anderen aufgeriffen, verwendet und möglicherweise weiter entwickelt wurden
\item welche Ansätze, Hypothesen, Theorien bzw. welche publizierenden Autoren besonders häufig übernommen wurden
\end{myitemize}

\begin{myenumerate}
\item damit lässt sich im Idealfall zeigen, welche wissenschaftlichen Auswirkungen bestimmte publizierte Ergebnisse, Ansätze oder Theorien hatten, indem diese von anderen aufgeriffen, verwendet und möglicherweise weiter entwickelt wurden,\footnote{Dieser Umstand ist in jedem Fall besonders von wissenschaftshistorischem Interesse\index{wissenschaftshistorisches Interesse} (vgl. jedoch auch die vorhandene, im Text w.\,u. zitierte Kritik, die an der Auswertung von Zitationsdatenbanken\index{Zitationsdatenbank} besteht).}
\item welche Ansätze, Hypothesen, Theorien bzw. welche publizierenden Autoren besonders häufig übernommen wurden,\footnote{Auch die rein quantitative Auswertung von Zitationsdatenbanken wird häufig als ein Aspekt der Auswertung in Evaluierungsverfahren\index{Evaluierungsverfahren} gesehen.}
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for deleting my tomatoes. I thought, there must be a default label, but no. Harald

Answer (score 5):

#### Adaptations

- I reduced your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)
- You have to set some `label`, e.g. `label=\arabic*.`

  - This is also told by the error message: `! Package enumitem Error: Undefined label.`

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[pagesize,parskip=half,DIV=11]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate]{leftmargin=*,label=\arabic*.,labelsep=3mm,after=\smallskip}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{myenumerate}
\item foo
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx for deleting my tomatoes. I thought, there must be a default label, but no. Harald